# Can you use Google Analytics to view individual visits?

Tags: google-analytics

Say I have an article which has been viewed 100 times and has an Average Visit Duration of 01:00:00 hrs. Is there any way I can break down those statistics - and see how long each individual visit lasted for?

(I should state that I'm not looking to find out information about particular IP addresses or anything like that. I just want to get some idea of the 'mode visit' - the time most people spent on the page.)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics doesn't provide enough detailed insights for invividual visitor details. If you want a more granular data try CardioLog Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right, Google doesn't provide that. I tend to use sitemeter in conjuction with Google. Not sure if I recommend sitemeter though. It does give specifics about individual visitors, but they are very flaky. I don't think I've ever gotten a response from their so-called "tech support" or anything else from them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't. Google Analytics doesn't provide individual visitor details as it violates the GA Terms of Service.

However there are a couple ways to get at or close to this information:

1) Create an advanced segment - use the "Page" dimension and include the URI of the article on your site. Apply it and then look at the city or service provider report - it will show you all visits that viewed the article.

2) Keep a copy of the tracking data sent to Google and process it with on premises web analytics software that doesn't have the same ToS/privacy restrictions.